# How to insert a row into database?

Tags: java, sql

I have written this code to add stuff to the database, however, when I try running it it does not work, i've been looking for ways to do it, but i just cant seem to find the solution, can anyone help?

```
String mySQL ="INSERT INTO Measurement (Level, Time, Date, TankID)"+"VALUES (textField1, currentTime,currentDate,(SELECT TankID FROM Tanks WHERE TankName = '2' AND Site_ID = '1'))";

stmt.executeUpdate(mySQL);
```

Comment: Please provide the text of the SQL exception

Comment: What’s error? Can u attach yo log output?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow you will find countless examples of using JDBC to insert a row into a database. Please search thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Both your SQL and prepared statement are malformed.  Try using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO Measurement (Level, Time, Date, TankID) ";
sql += "SELECT ?, ?, ?, TankID ";
sql += "FROM Tanks ";
sql += "WHERE TankName = '2' AND Site_ID = '1'";

stmt.setString(1, textField1);
stmt.setString(2, currentTime);  // not sure about the type here
stmt.setString(3, currentDate);  // also not sure about the type

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that I am unsure about both the Java and SQL binding types of the columns for `currentTime` and `currentDate`.  If not string, then the above would have to change slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `PreparedStatement` to properly set the first parameter of the insert query and check the documentation of your DB server to use existing functions to get current time and date.

For example, mySQL has functions [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [`CURTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime)

```java
String query = "INSERT INTO Measurement (Level, Time, Date, TankID) "
    + "VALUES (?, CURTIME(), CURDATE(), (SELECT TankID FROM Tanks WHERE TankName = '2' AND Site_ID = '1'))";

try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    statement.setString(1, textField1); // could be textField1.getText() or textField1.getValue()
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Your insert syntax wouldn't even run on some SQL databases, and besides that, it likely is not the logic which the OP wants here (unless that subquery would really only return a single record).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Database type change the connection details

[Follow this Link for creating JDBC Connection and Inserting data](https://www.codejava.net/ides/intellij/getting-familiar-with-intellij-idea-tutorial-for-beginner)

If you did the above steps please ignore this..